# Authentication error when initializing Google EE in QGIS 3.16.1

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm having a hard time initializing GEE in QGIS. I've tried this on many different machines but no luck.

I've successfully installed Google Earth Engine in the QGIS plugin repository, but when it starts I'm prompted with this error message:

```
TypeError: get_authorization_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'code_challenge' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 230, in get_persistent_credentials
    tokens = json.load(open(oauth.get_credentials_path()))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hogan/.config/earthengine/credentials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_auth.py", line 19, in init
    ee.Initialize()
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 114, in Initialize
    credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 241, in get_persistent_credentials
    'Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by '
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py", line 25, in classFactory
    from .ee_plugin import GoogleEarthEnginePlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 792, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_plugin.py", line 26, in 
    ee_plugin.ee_auth.init()
  File "C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_auth.py", line 21, in init
    authenticate()
  File "C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\ee_auth.py", line 32, in authenticate
    auth_url = ee.oauth.get_authorization_url()
TypeError: get_authorization_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'code_challenge'


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.1-Hannover Hannover, b381a90dca 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\Scripts
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\python37.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/hogan/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows
```

When I've tried to troubleshoot this and manually import in the Python Console, I'm able to import ee successfully, print the version number, and then when I run `ee.Authenticate()` it sends me to the page to copy the link - HOWEVER no dialog box returns for me to enter that authorization code, and the system seems to time out. See below:

```
print(ee.__version__)
0.1.224
ee.Authenticate()
To authorize access needed by Earth Engine, open the following URL in a web browser and follow the instructions. If the web browser does not start automatically, please manually browse the URL below.

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=517222506229-vsmmajv00ul0bs7p89v5m89qs8eb9359.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fearthengine+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&code_challenge=plLB7m2RVrMuL4tLJn9tyYmTrd4IgHw80v7VpwDJs6E&code_challenge_method=S256

The authorization workflow will generate a code, which you should paste in the box below. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 86, in Authenticate
    oauth.authenticate(authorization_code, quiet, code_verifier)
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\oauth.py", line 233, in authenticate
    _obtain_and_write_token(None, code_verifier)  # Will prompt for auth_code.
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\oauth.py", line 137, in _obtain_and_write_token
    auth_code = input('Enter verification code: ')
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
ee.Initialize()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 230, in get_persistent_credentials
    tokens = json.load(open(oauth.get_credentials_path()))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\hogan/.config/earthengine/credentials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 114, in Initialize
    credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 241, in get_persistent_credentials
    'Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by '
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
import ee
print(ee.__version__)
0.1.224
ee.Authenticate()
To authorize access needed by Earth Engine, open the following URL in a web browser and follow the instructions. If the web browser does not start automatically, please manually browse the URL below.

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=517222506229-vsmmajv00ul0bs7p89v5m89qs8eb9359.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fearthengine+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&code_challenge=_U4vCbBK3y96M4NCHviaxUyuuSOtaXf_z3USrh6xucA&code_challenge_method=S256

The authorization workflow will generate a code, which you should paste in the box below. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 86, in Authenticate
    oauth.authenticate(authorization_code, quiet, code_verifier)
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\oauth.py", line 233, in authenticate
    _obtain_and_write_token(None, code_verifier)  # Will prompt for auth_code.
  File "C:\Users\hogan\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\oauth.py", line 137, in _obtain_and_write_token
    auth_code = input('Enter verification code: ')
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```

Anyone else had this problem or know of a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'map' from 'ee_plugin'
  (C:/Users/xfjx333/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py)
```

I face the same problem at the beginning, but after making several attempts, finally, I made it. I list the attempts I made here, hope it will help you:
In the beginning, I installed  GEE plugin version 0.0.3 in QGIS version 3.16.2-Hannover, then it does not pop-up the interface which not asking for authentication, so I try to download the newest plugin version https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1x8QCQ-5CzjQEk-cNEyMU87Xz5S8LaR7s (from Github https://github.com/gee-community/qgis-earthengine-plugin/issues/76)

1. Try to authenticate outside the plugin first. For example using: `conda install earthengine-api` and then run `earthengine authenticate`.
2. Restart the QGIS and uninstall the current GEE plugin,  install from the zip as I list above;
3. Restart the QGIS and run the following testing code from https://github.com/giswqs/qgis-earthengine-examples/blob/master/Gena/map_center_object.py

My QGIS is the standalone one.